# Swift 2, UItableview Does not load cells in ViewDidLoad func

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have looked all over google and this forum but cant seem to understand what the problem is, the things is that if I add a button after the view loaded and click on it all the cells are shown from Sql database, BUT if I insert the same func in ViewDidLoad the cells are shown yet completely empty.
I tried to add a print right before the insert command to see if a nil val has been doing so, but no, the val print corretly

this is the viewdidload func:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    Picker.delegate = self
    Picker.dataSource = self
    ImagesLabel.inputView = Picker
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self


    GetTodaysMonthAndYear()
    InsertCellFromDataBase()


}
```

and the add cells to array func:

```
func InsertCellFromDataBase()
{
    ArrayOfSpendings.removeAll()
    tableView.reloadData()

    let (resultSet, base) = SD.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Spendings WHERE Month = ? and Year = ?", withArgs: ["\(Int(MonthPickertext.text!)!)","\(Int(YearPickerText.text!)!)"])

    if base == nil {

        for eachRow in resultSet{

            let name = eachRow["Name"]?.asString()
            let price = eachRow["Price"]?.asString()
            let freq = eachRow["Freq"]?.asString()
            let img = eachRow["Image"]?.asString()
            let importency = eachRow["Importency"]?.asString()
            let y = eachRow["Year"]?.asInt()
            print(y)
            let spend = Spendings(nameInArray: name!,amountInArray: price!,perMonthOrOnceInArray: freq!,imageInArray: img!, importent: importency!)

            ArrayOfSpendings.append(spend)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

and the tableview func:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return ArrayOfSpendings.count

}

//Add new cell

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    print(indexPath.row)
    let spend = ArrayOfSpendings[indexPath.row]

    if spend.Importency == "Yes"
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }


            print(spend.Name)
    cell.setCell(spend.Name,AmountInCell: spend.Amount,MonthInCell: spend.PerMonthOrOnce,ImageInCell: spend.ImageInCell)




   return cell
```

}

Comment: in InsertCellFromDataBase function call reload after for loop not in loop

Comment: thank you for replying yet the answer you gave did not solved it

Answer (score 0):

what does `GetTodaysMonthAndYear` do?  More specifically, when is `MonthPickertext.text` set?  It looks like this isn't defined during `viewDidLoad` which means that your `resultSet` will not be defined.

When you access this function from a button - after the view has fully loaded and everything has been populated, then it will all work.

To make this work within `viewDidLoad` - try accessing the data that you're going to put into the date fields, rather than the contents of the field

Comment: the weird thing is that every field or variables that the database or the table is with content for sure, I have checked it with print func. and still the table shows empty, the array count is right, the var are with content, the func work outside the viewdidload, what is worng? what am I missing

Comment: in your method `InsertCellFromDataBase`, you could try printing out the query that you're using - `"SELECT * FROM Spendings WHERE Month = ? and Year = ?", withArgs: ["\(Int(MonthPickertext.text!)!)","\(Int(YearPickerText.text!)!)"])`  and just confirm that the month and year are populated correctly

Comment: Yes it is populated one line after the query is asked

Comment: sorry - I'm stumped :-(

Comment: lets think together , I have a database with info, the func insertcell works fine out side the viewdidload. the problem is probably with something not being loaded besides the var . now the weird part is when I have the insertCell inside viewdidload and the cells are empty, it seems that I cannot change the empty cells even outside viewdidload

Comment: could you add the code for `GetTodaysMonthAndYear`?

Comment: cant its says to many charecters.... anyway I have tried to remove query and load all info in table, still same problem.... maybe the Cell Class itself is the problem?